# Passing context into timer..is this safe

Tags: android, android-context

I'm using a timer which needs context.
Now I have the following code :

```
   mContext=context;
    mEventID=eventID;
    CountDownTimer cdTimer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // Do nothing onTick... Sorry
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            int deletedRows = mContext.getContentResolver().delete()
            // ..rest of code
        }
    };
    cdTimer.start();
```

Is this safe to use , or may I be leaking the context here?
btw. This is in a `broadcastreceiver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not pass the Context into the Thread, instead refer to it by it's parent name.

something like this

```
class MyClass {
...
CountDownTimer cdTimer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // Do nothing onTick... Sorry
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            int deletedRows = myClass.this.context.getContentResolver().delete()
            // ..rest of code
        }
    };

...

}
```

So you probably need to call the context by your broadcast receiver's name eg: `MyReceiver.this.context` assuming `context` is a member of the class.